# Erlang process queues best practices?

Tags: erlang, queue, process

I've built a process queue implementation that creates a pool of worker processes that receive a payload message with the datum to work on. When that process is done, it sends a message back to the pool and the pool manager re-enqueues that process ID for use.

My question is this: is it better to discard the process and just spawn a new one? Or recycle it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Process construction in Erlang is *extremely* lightweight. Discard and create a new one.

Comment: Definitely discard it. Only keep it if there is some specific reason for reusing the process, never for efficiency.

Comment: You'll also notice that your code becomes much cleaner when you don't reuse process. Also, less opportunities for errors or bugs creeping in.